# In my java paint application, paintComponent overridden twice when i call it in my mouselisteners

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage, paintcomponent

With this code i am trying to first create a bufferedimage as my canvas which i will draw something then i want to save each image to a linkedlist.However, when i use my tools to draw something this method overriden twice. Also i dont understand the logic behind this override totally.

`

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    if (image != null) {
        g2d = image.createGraphics();

        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        setBackground(backgroundColor);        
        list.add(image);           
        list.remove(list.size()-1);        
        g.drawImage(list.get(list.size()-1), 0, 0, this);
        g2d.dispose();

     // a();
    } else{
        image = new BufferedImage(1920,1080,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        System.out.println("XXXXXXX");
        list.add(image);
        g.drawImage(list.get(0), 0, 0, null);
        list.remove(0);
    }


  }
public void addLabel(JLabel label){
    add(label);
    repaint();
}

public void setBackgroundColor(Color color){
    backgroundColor=color;
    repaint();
}

public void undo(){

}

 public void clear(){

     image = new BufferedImage(1920, 1080, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
     g2d = image.createGraphics();
     g2d.setPaint(backgroundColor);

     list.remove(list);
     list.add(image);

     g2d.drawImage(image,0,0,null);

     g2d.setPaint(backgroundColor);

     repaint();
 }

 public void clearLast(){
     if(!list.isEmpty()){           
         g2d = image.createGraphics();           
         g2d.drawImage(list.get(list.size()-1), 0, 0, null);                        
         repaint();
     }

 }`
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: how can i fix this of course :3

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Calling `setBackground` in your `paintComponent` could generate additional repaint requests, you should never change the state of a component from within any paint method